# Split string row from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array with string rows:

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "Kungsvägen 118 A 1969-06-17"
  [1]=>
  string(24) "Skolgatan 1 B 1969-06-17"
  [2]=>
  string(24) "Skolgatan 1 B 1980-05-22"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "Myntvägen 8 1980-05-22"
  [4]=>
  string(24) "Skolgatan 1 B 1993-05-09"
  [5]=>
  string(24) "Skolgatan 1 B 1989-06-28"
  [6]=>
  string(24) "Skolgatan 1 B 1991-03-17"
  [7]=>
  string(24) "Skolgatan 1 B 1989-10-30"
  [8]=>
  string(33) "Gasslanda VÄSTERGÅRD 2 1980-10-30"
  [9]=>
  string(24) "Skolgatan 1 B 1980-10-30"
  [10]=>
  string(24) "Skolgatan 1 B 1990-05-01"
  [11]=>
  string(21) "Ågatan 6 A 1990-05-01"
}
```

The string contains adress and date of birth. I want to split/separate this two. How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried? Did you e.g. look at array callbacks? Do you have a regular expression or some other method that splits an example of such a string?

Comment: Are all the birth dates reliably in the same format YYYY-MM-DD? If so, you can use simple substring manipulation...

Comment: loop through array and use substring to get last 10 char...you will get date

Comment: @berkes: I've tried  the date_parse function in PHP to get the date of births, but I dont know how to get the addresses?

Comment: @Undefined_variable: The array also contains other addresses with more charachters.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: How can I do string manipulation when the addresses size differs?

Comment: @user500468 By chopping off the last 10 characters from each string, which never differ. Assuming you want the resultant address as a single unit, and don't plan to further parse it down.

Comment: @user500468 e.g. passing `-10` [as the `$start` param to `substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Thank you. When I chopping of the last 10 characters, I get only the addresses, correct?

Comment: Calling `substr($str, -10)` will return only the date. To get the address, you would then need to call substr() again for the address passing the (total length - 10) to get everything _except_ the final 10.  Alternatively, you could [use `str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) also passing (total length - 10) as the length param.

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you

```
$ar = array(
  0=>"Kungsvägen 118 A 1969-06-17",
  1=>"Skolgatan 1 B 1969-06-17",
  2=>"Skolgatan 1 B 1980-05-22",
  3=>"Myntvägen 8 1980-05-22",
  4=>"Skolgatan 1 B 1993-05-09",
  5=>"Skolgatan 1 B 1989-06-28",
  6=>"Skolgatan 1 B 1991-03-17",
  7=>"Skolgatan 1 B 1989-10-30",
  8=>"Gasslanda VÄSTERGÅRD 2 1980-10-30",
  9=>"Skolgatan 1 B 1980-10-30",
  10=>"Skolgatan 1 B 1990-05-01",
  11=>"Ågatan 6 A 1990-05-01"
);

foreach ($ar as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key]['address'] = substr($value, 1,-10);
    $arr[$key]['dob'] = substr($value, -10);
}
print_r($arr);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [address] => ungsvÃ¤gen 118 A 
            [dob] => 1969-06-17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [address] => kolgatan 1 B 
            [dob] => 1969-06-17
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [address] => kolgatan 1 B 
            [dob] => 1980-05-22
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [address] => yntvÃ¤gen 8 
            [dob] => 1980-05-22
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [address] => kolgatan 1 B 
            [dob] => 1993-05-09
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [address] => kolgatan 1 B 
            [dob] => 1989-06-28
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [address] => kolgatan 1 B 
            [dob] => 1991-03-17
        )
  ..... upto last element
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the address by making date the delimiter, then get the date.

```
$final = array();
foreach($inputarr as $value) {
  $address = preg_split('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $value);
  preg_match('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/', $value, $date);
  array_push($final, array($address[0], $date[0])); 
}

var_dump($final);
```